# javascript onunload function for getting mouse coordinate returns negative values in IE10 compact view

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I am writing a javascript function for getting mouse coordinate in jsp body
onunload .Its working good in IE8 but i will return negative values in IE10
Compatibility view.

my code is,

```
window.event.clientX;
window.event.clientY;
```

Please help me for getting correct coordinates in IE10 compact view. In onunload java script 
function.

Because I want to close my session while close the browser by using https://i.stack.imgur.com/akZ22.jpg button.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect mouse coordinates in your `onunload` event (and why do you need them?)? This is no mouse event, so I wouldn't try to read mouse coordinates. Instead, if you really insist on having those, read them through a handler for `onmousemove` and store them.

But either way: Are you sure what you're doing is necessary? At least for PHP sessions by default are only valid till the browser window is closed anyway. I'm sure JSP offers similar functionality. Possibly you just have to set the session's cookie values on your own.